# How to stop the <audio> file from playing when i hide the <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a music player using HTML, CSS and Vanilla Js. I am facing these problems:

1.How to stop the song of first artist from playing when i click on the second artist?

2. Also, when I start off by clicking on a particular div (Mozart, GnR, etc.), I have to click twice before the player loads up.

I am new to JavaScript, so I am not able to grasp the concept of using play() and pause() functions for my audio file (the "Promise uncaught error"), so it would be great if you explain it to me without relating to this particular concept. Also, if you have some very good documents on the Promise , kindly post the link too!

Thank you. :)

```js
function mozart() {
  var playArea = document.getElementById('playArea');
  if (playArea.style.display == 'none') {
    playArea.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playArea.style.display = 'none';
  }

  var playSong = document.getElementsByClassName('mozartSong')[0];
  if (playSong.style.display == 'none') {
    playSong.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playSong.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function gnr() {
  var playArea = document.getElementById('playArea');
  if (playArea.style.display == 'none') {
    playArea.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playArea.style.display = 'none';
  }

  var playSong = document.getElementsByClassName('gnrSong')[0];
  if (playSong.style.display == 'none') {
    playSong.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playSong.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function lz() {
  var playArea = document.getElementById('playArea');
  if (playArea.style.display == 'none') {
    playArea.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playArea.style.display = 'none';
  }

  var playSong = document.getElementsByClassName('ledzepplinSong')[0];
  if (playSong.style.display == 'none') {
    playSong.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playSong.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function metallica() {
  var playArea = document.getElementById('playArea');
  if (playArea.style.display == 'none') {
    playArea.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playArea.style.display = 'none';
  }

  var playSong = document.getElementsByClassName('metallicaSong')[0];
  if (playSong.style.display == 'none') {
    playSong.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playSong.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function scorpion() {
  var playArea = document.getElementById('playArea');
  if (playArea.style.display == 'none') {
    playArea.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playArea.style.display = 'none';
  }

  var playSong = document.getElementsByClassName('scorpionSong')[0];
  if (playSong.style.display == 'none') {
    playSong.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playSong.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function acdc() {
  var playArea = document.getElementById('playArea');
  if (playArea.style.display == 'none') {
    playArea.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playArea.style.display = 'none';
  }

  var playSong = document.getElementsByClassName('acdcSong')[0];
  if (playSong.style.display == 'none') {
    playSong.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playSong.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function queen() {
  var playArea = document.getElementById('playArea');
  if (playArea.style.display == 'none') {
    playArea.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playArea.style.display = 'none';
  }

  var playSong = document.getElementsByClassName('queenSong')[0];
  if (playSong.style.display == 'none') {
    playSong.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    playSong.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .maincontent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .maincontent .header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #8ED2C9;
}

.container .maincontent .mainSec {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container .maincontent .mainSec .keys {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FF7A5A;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .maincontent .mainSec .keys .mozart,
.gnr,
.ledzepplin,
.metallica,
.scorpion,
.acdc,
.queen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5%;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
}

button: hover {
  color:
}

.container .maincontent .mainSec .contentSec {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFB85F;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .maincontent .mainSec .contentSec #playArea {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fcf4d9;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

.container .maincontent .mainSec .contentSec #playArea .mozartSong,
.gnrSong,
.ledzepplinSong,
.metallicaSong,
.scorpionSong,
.acdcSong,
.queenSong {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Music Player</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="music.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="maincontent">
      <div class="header"></div>
      <!--Header div ends-->
      <div class="mainSec">
        <div class="keys">
          <div class="mozart">
            <div class="mozartBtn">
              <button class="Mozart" onclick="mozart()">Mozart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Mozart div ends-->

          <div class="gnr">
            <div class="gnrBtn">
              <button class="Gnr" onclick="gnr()">GnR</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Gnr div ends-->

          <div class="ledzepplin">
            <div class="ledzepplingBtn">
              <button class="LedZepplin" onclick="lz()">LedZepplin</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Led Zepplin div ends-->

          <div class="metallica">
            <div class="metallicaBtn">
              <button class="Metallica" onclick="metallica()">Metallica</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Metallica div ends-->

          <div class="scorpion">
            <div class="scorpionBtn">
              <button class="Scorpion" onclick="scorpion()">Scorpion</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Scorpion div ends-->

          <div class="acdc">
            <div class="acdcBtn">
              <button class="ACDC" onclick="acdc()">AcDc</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--ACDC div ends-->

          <div class="queen">
            <div class="queenBtn">
              <button class="Queen" onclick="queen()">Queen</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Queen div ends-->
        </div>
        <!--keys div ends-->
        <div class="contentSec">
          <div id="playArea">
            <div class="mozartSong">
              <audio controls>
         <source src="music/mozart.wav" type="audio/wav" id="curSong">
        </audio>
            </div>

            <div class="gnrSong">
              <audio controls>
         <source src="music/gnr.wav" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
            </div>

            <div class="ledzepplinSong">
              <audio controls>
         <source src="music/ledzepplin.wav" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
            </div>

            <div class="metallicaSong">
              <audio controls>
         <source src="music/metallica.wav" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
            </div>

            <div class="scorpionSong">
              <audio controls>
         <source src="music/scorpion.wav" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
            </div>

            <div class="acdcSong">
              <audio controls>
         <source src="music/acdc.wav" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
            </div>

            <div class="queenSong">
              <audio controls> 
         <source src="music/queen.wav" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="music.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`

Comment: `div`s can't be "_closed_", they can be hidden, or removed only. If you removed a div, all the elements inside of it would be removed too. See what you can do with the [audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) interface.

Comment: First You should (not absolutely needed but better) replace all your functions with only one and pass in the song as an argument instead of having the same function repeated for all the songs. This way you can dynamically add the song in instead of loading everything on pageload which will take more data.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Teemu

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested, you have too many functions with the same functionality.

I've made it a bit easier for you. This will replace the audio tag so the previous audio will stop. Just change `path to your song directory`

```
<script>
  var playSong = function(songName) {
    var audio = document.getElementById('playArea');
    var source = document.getElementById('playSong');
    source.src = 'path to your song directory' + songName + '.wav';
    audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
    audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away
  }
</script>

<div class="keys">
  <div class="mozart">
    <div class="mozartBtn">
      <button class="Mozart" onclick="playSong('Mozart')">Mozart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Mozart div ends-->

  <div class="gnr">
    <div class="gnrBtn">
      <button class="Gnr" onclick="playSong('GnR')">GnR</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Gnr div ends-->

  <div class="ledzepplin">
    <div class="ledzepplingBtn">
      <button class="LedZepplin" onclick="playSong('LedZepplin')">LedZepplin</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Led Zepplin div ends-->

  <div class="metallica">
    <div class="metallicaBtn">
      <button class="Metallica" onclick="playSong('Metallica')">Metallica</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Metallica div ends-->

  <div class="scorpion">
    <div class="scorpionBtn">
      <button class="Scorpion" onclick="playSong('Scorpion')">Scorpion</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Scorpion div ends-->

  <div class="acdc">
    <div class="acdcBtn">
      <button class="ACDC" onclick="playSong('AcDc')">AcDc</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--ACDC div ends-->

  <div class="queen">
    <div class="queenBtn">
      <button class="Queen" onclick="playSong('Queen')">Queen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Queen div ends-->
</div>

<audio id="playArea" controls>
  <source src="music/mozart.wav" type="audio/wav" id="playSong">
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but it is again throwing an error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.

Comment: Late reply sorry. Time difference in our countries I suppose. Still going to help you. Will you please post your updated code so that I can try recreate the issue?

Comment: It's happening because the previous one is still playing. I'll need to look it up a bit later if I get a chance. You can however try check if you can find a solution to check if audio is playing and if yes to pause it first then play the one clicked on. Slight function change with `if` statement.